# Wofür steht „dran“ in „spät dran sein“?

Tags: phrase, colloquial

Die Bedeutung ist mir schon klar. Aber ich wollte fragen, was die Abkürzung *dran* ersetzt und ob sie immer nötig ist?

Hat *ich bin spät* nicht dieselbe Bedeutung?

Answer (score 10):

"Ich bin spät" ist Englisch mit deutschen Wörtern (I'm late). Im Deutschen ist so eine Formulierung aber ungebräuchlich. Üblicherweise sagt man

- Ich komme zu spät
- Ich bin spät dran

Dabei ist nicht recht klar, was "dran" eigentlich ersetzt. Es ist einfach eine feste Wendung.

Comment: _dran_ (ursprünglich _daran_)  kann manchmal _an der Reihe_ ersetzen

Comment: Reihe paßt hier nicht so recht. Vom Sinn her müßte das "dran" mal so was wie "am Gehen/Hingehen/Heimgehen" gewesen sein.

Comment: Vielleicht von *dabei/daran sein, etwas zu tun*.

Comment: Ja, wäre eine  Möglichkeit: Ich bin spät daran, zur Kirche zu gehen. Ich muß mich beeilen.

Answer (score 3):

Des Rätsels Lösung ist eigentlich ganz einfach.

[Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/dran) sagt, das dran

> eine direkte räumliche Berührung ausdrückend

bedeutet.

Das heißt man könnte auch sagen.

> Ich berühre das Ziel spät.
>
> Oder: Ich bin spät da.
>
> Oder: Ich komme zu spät am Ziel an.

Also:

> Ich werde zu spät da (wo ich hin will) an(kommen). = Ich bin zu spät dran.

Beziehungsweise:

> Nach aktueller Lage bin ich im Zeitverzug *da* wo ich in will pünktlich *ran* zu kommen. (dran zu kommen.)

Dran ist also eine Verkürzung von da ran zu kommen. Oder da hin zu kommen.

Einfach zu sagen ich bin spät, reicht nicht, weil noch gesagt werden muss, wozu man spät ist. Im Englischen kann man zwar sagen *I’m late*. Aber normalerweise gehört dazu noch, die Aussage zu was man zu spät kommt.

> I’m late — for a meeting.

Comment: Sehr schön, das macht es so viel logischer! In dem Sinne ist *spät dran sein* verwandt mit *dran kommen* in der Schule. +1 (würde mehr geben)

Answer (score 2):

*Spät* ist kein Adjektiv, das auf einen selbst zutreffen könnte – insbesondere nicht, wenn man selbst verspätet ist. *Spät* kann sich auf die Uhrzeit beziehen:

> Zu *später* Stunde
>   Der *späte* Abend

Oder aber auf etwas, was zu einer späten Uhrzeit stattfindet,

> Der *späte* Zug ist derjenige, der spät am Abend fährt.
>   Die *späte* Feier beginnt erst recht spät in der Nacht.

oder jemanden, der zu einer späten Uhrzeit auftaucht.

> Die Party läuft zwar schon zwei Stunden, aber ich erwarte noch zwei *späte* Gäste.

Daraus erkennt man schon, dass ein Mensch schwerlich spät sein kann. Sie kann zwar *verspätet sein* oder *Verspätung haben*, aber eben nicht nur *spät sein*.

Da beide Ersatzausdrücke recht lang sind, hat sich die verkürzte Form *spät dran sein* eingebürgert.

Alternativ bietet sich das Adverb *spät* an:

> Ich komme *spät*.

---

Nachtrag: Wie Matthias zurecht in Kommentaren bemerkt, und dann auch [in einer weiteren Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/23499/9091) weiter ausgeführt hat, kann *spät* nicht prädikativ gebraucht werden – es kann also grundsätzlich nicht mit dem Verb *sein* an ein Substantiv gekoppelt werden.

> Der späte Zug;
>   Aber nicht: <strike>Der Zug ist spät</strike>

Erlaubt ist wiederum:

> **Es** ist spät.

Answer (score 2):

Die Wendung "spät dran sein" ist schon recht lange in Gebrauch. Google Books findet einige Belege (in der heute noch aktuellen Bedeutung) aus der zweiten Hälfte des 19. Jahrhunderts. Der älteste, wenn ich nichts übersehen habe, stammt aus dem Jahr 1849

> ... daß ich mit meiner Gratulation so spät dran bin ... [Hieroglyphen oder Magisches Gedenkbuch des ehrlichen Michels](https://books.google.de/books?id=foFCAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA30&dq=%22sp%C3%A4t+dran%22&hl=de&sa=X&ei=tPBkVcfSMYGAU968gPgN&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22sp%C3%A4t%20dran%22&f=false)

Richtig populär wurde sie aber erst seit den 30er Jahren des 20. Jahrhunderts, wie Google Ngram [eindrucksvoll zeigt](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sp%C3%A4t+dran&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csp%C3%A4t%20dran%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csp%C3%A4t%20dran%3B%2Cc1).

Hinsichtlich der Bedeutung des "dran" (was ja eine Verkürzung von "daran" darstellt) glaube ich, dass hier eine Verallgemeinerung von Wendungen der Form "an etwas + Verb" vorliegt, also z.B. "an etwas denken" oder "an etwas arbeiten". Insbesondere gibt es einen sehr frühen Beleg für die Verwendung "spät dran sein" in der Bedeutung "zu später Stunde an etwas arbeiten", nämlich

> Also ein Schmid / der mus bey seinem Ambos sein / vnd seiner Schmitte warten / vnd wird mat vom fewr / vnd erbeit sich müde vber der Esse
>   Das hemmern schlegt jm die Ohren vol / vnd sihet drauff / wie er das Werck recht mache
>   vnd mus dencken / wie ers fertige / vnd früe vnd **spat dran sein** / das ers fein auserbeite.

Das ist aus dem Buch Sirach, Kapitel 39, in der [Luther-Bibel von 1545](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Luther,+Martin/Luther-Bibel+1545/Apokryphe+Schriften+des+Alten+Testaments/Das+Buch+Jesus+Sirach/Jesus+Sirach+39)

Wer "spät *dran* ist", arbeitet (oder denkt) also noch spät *an* etwas; ein naheliegender Grund dafür ist ein heranrückender Termin.

Warum "Ich bin spät" nicht geht und welche sonstigen Alternativen es gibt, ist in den anderen Antworten bereits hinreichend erklärt.