# Warum „der späte Gast“, aber nicht „Der Gast ist spät“?

Tags: grammar, adjective

Normalerweise kann man die Phrase

> Das ist *Artikel Adjektiv Substantiv*.

umstellen zu

> Das *Substantiv* ist *Adjektiv*.

Also zum Beispiel

> Das ist ein rotes Auto.
>   Das Auto ist rot.

Beim Nachdenken über [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/23482/9091) ist mir aufgefallen, dass dies nicht für das Adjektiv *spät* gilt:

> Wer klopft da?
>   Das ist ein später Gast.
>   <strike>Das ist ein Gast, der spät ist.</strike>

Diese Einschränkung gilt nicht nur in Verwendung mit Personen, sondern ebenso auch mit Gegenständen:

> Dieses Bild ist ein spätes Werk von XY.
>   <strike>Dieses Bild von XY ist spät.</strike>

Meine Fragen:

- Warum ist das so?
- Hat das Phänomen einen Namen?
- Gibt es (neben dem naheliegenden *früh*) noch weitere Adjektive, auf die das zutrifft? Wenn ja, hat es dort denselben Grund?

(Zur letzten Teilfrage: Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob *links*/*rechts* hierzu zu zählen wären. *Die Tür ist links* kann man zwar sagen, wird aber m.E. mit etwas anderer Bedeutung gebraucht als *die linke Tür*.)

Comment: _Arm_ wäre noch so ein Fall, und zwar nicht _arm_ im Sinne von _mit wenig Geld_, sondern von _bedauernswert_. Wie bei _spät_ geht es wieder mit _dran_:  _Das arme Kind friert._ _Das Kind ist arm dran._

Comment: @chirlu Das Beispiel hat mir sofort gefallen, aber damit das "wie bei  spät" andere nicht auf die falsche Fährte führt: in beiden Fällen wird der Satz durch das "dran" grammatikalisch richtig, aber nur bei "arm" behält er die Bedeutung der attributiven Verwendung.

Comment: Zur Tür: Eine linke Tür ist eine Tür, bei der sich die Angeln, Bänder oder Scharniere auf der linken Seite der Tür befinden, wenn man auf der Seite der Tür steht bei der diese Beschläge sichtbar sind. Siehe auch: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Öffnungsrichtung_von_Türen Es könnte aber auch eine Tür sein, die sich links von etwas anderem befindet.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Interessant... Allerdings finde ich in dem Artikel nur "links angeschlagene Tür", "Linkstür" und "DIN-links". Wo steht, dass auch "linke Tür" in diesem Sinn benutzt werden kann?

Comment: @Matthias: Ich weiß es nicht wo das steht. Wenn du das schriftlich von einer anderen Quelle als von mir haben möchtest, musst du selber googeln. Ich kann dir aber versichern: Wenn du in einem einschlägigen Fachgeschäft nach einer linken Tür fragst, wird man dich ganz sicher in diesem Sinn verstehen. Ich habe auch Handwerker und Wohnungsmakler mehrfach in diesem Sinn von linken und rechten Türen (und nicht von »Linkstüren«) sprechen hören.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich glaub es dir mal  ;-) Das wäre dann also ein weiteres Beispiel für den von [chirlu](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/23507/9091) erwähnten Fall, dass ein Adjektiv in manchen Bedeutungen defektiv sein kann, in anderen nicht.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Und wenn man dasselbe in kleinerem Maßstab betrachtet, kommt man bei Lego-Türen an, und findet zumindest für den stellenweisen tatsächlichen Gebrauch in der von dir beschriebenen Form [Beispiele](http://www.ebay.de/itm/LEGO-32bc01-Rote-linke-Tur-1x2x3-60er-aus-119-357-580-360-347-342-346-353-350-/121570431764?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_77&hash=item1c4e299314).

Comment: Warum eigentlich nicht? "Der Gast ist spät" (oder der Bus, Zug,...) habe ich durchaus schon gehört. Holprig, aber geht. (Keine Ahnung, ob das umgangssprachlich ist)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Die Duden-Grammatik (4. Auflage 1984, herausgegeben und bearbeitet von Günter Drosdowski u.a.) bezeichnet Adjektive, die nicht nach Belieben attributiv, prädikativ und adverbial verwendet werden können, als *defekte Adjektive*.

Die Frage richtet sich konkret auf Adjektive, die attributiv, aber nicht prädikativ gebraucht werden können, jedenfalls nicht in allen ihren Bedeutungen. Diese ordnet die Duden-Grammatik folgenden Kategorien zu:

1. Adjektive, die die räumliche oder zeitliche Lage beschreiben: *der obere Rand*, *das hiesige Theater*, *der gestrige Tag*;
2. Adjektive, die Besitz, Herkunft, Bereich, Gebiet oder Stoff angeben: *die ärztliche Praxis*, *orientalische Teppiche*, *der städtische Beamte*, *die wirtschaftliche Sicherheit*, *ein hölzerner Griff*;
3. sogenannte Zahladjektive: *die ganze Bevölkerung*, *in den siebziger Jahren*, *der erste Besucher*, *der letzte Mohikaner*, *andere Menschen*;
4. bestimmte Partizipien in festen Verbindungen wie *in schwindelnder Höhe*, *in betrunkenem Zustand*, wo die Tätigkeit nicht tatsächlich dem Substantiv zugeschrieben wird (nicht der Zustand hat sich betrunken);
5. Adjektive, die eine Wiederholung in bestimmten Abständen bezeichnen: *die monatliche Sitzung*;
6. Adjektive in Verbindung mit Tätersubstantiven, die nicht die Person an sich, sondern die Tätigkeit näher beschreiben: *ein schlechter Koch*, *eine gute Rednerin*.

Die Adjektive der 5. und 6. Kategorie können im Gegensatz zu den anderen immerhin noch adverbial verwendet werden:

> Die Sitzung findet monatlich statt. Er kocht schlecht.

Zu beachten ist, daß die eingeschränkte Verwendung dieser Adjektive bedeutungsspezifisch ist. Werden sie in anderer, beispielsweise übertragener, Bedeutung benutzt, kann die Einschränkung entfallen:

> Die Schublade hat einen hölzernen Griff. Der Griff ist aus Holz. (*nicht:* ist hölzern)
>   Er hat eine hölzerne Rede gehalten. Die Rede war hölzern.

Comment: Hm, ich überlege selbst, ob das eigentlich (noch?) für alle Fälle aus der 6. Kategorie zutrifft. Ich glaube, ich könnte sagen _Die Rednerin ist gut_, und man würde es auf ihre rhetorischen Fähigkeiten beziehen. Andererseits, bei _Der Raucher ist stark_ würde man wohl an Körperkraft denken und nicht an jemanden, der viel raucht, also _ein starker Raucher_ ist.

Comment: Ich würde nicht verstehen, was mit "ein starker Raucher" gemeint ist und habe diese Formulierung noch nie (bewusst) wahrgenommen. Ich würde das eher als "Kettenraucher" ausdrücken, wobei sich die Problematik nicht ergibt. Unter einem "starken Raucher" würde ich ebenso einen physisch kräftigen Raucher verstehen.

Comment: Danke für die ausführliche und aufschlußreiche Antwort. "Spät" würde dann in die erste Kategorie fallen, oder? --- Die Konstruktion "Die Rednerin ist gut" wird m.E. heutzutage durchaus benutzt. "Wie war's in der Oper"? "Die Solistin war richtig gut, aber sonst war es ziemlich langweilig."

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Mach mal bitte eine Google-NGram-Suche nach 'starker Raucher'.

Comment: Danke, das war sehr lehrreich. Aber eine Frage drängt sich auf: Ist „defekt“ selbst ein defektes Adjektiv? Kann man „Das Adjektiv »spät« ist defekt“ sagen, oder greift hier Punkt 4?

Comment: @Ralph: _Defekt_ ist nur insofern defekt, als es nicht adverbial gebraucht werden kann; das hat aber einfach inhaltliche Gründe (es ergibt keinen Sinn, zu sagen, daß etwas „auf defekte Weise“ passiert). Attributiver und prädikativer Gebrauch sind dagegen beide möglich.

Answer (score 0):

"Das ist ein Gast, der spät ist. " ist absolut korrekt und diesen Ausdruck würde jeder verstehen. Da man mit diesem Satz betonen möchte, wer denn an der Tür klopft (nämlich ein Gast), ist diese Form des Satzes eher unüblich, da man so die Eigenschaft "spät" in den Vordergrund rücken würde.

"Spät" im Nebensatz wird in der Regel in Bezug auf die zeitliche Ankunft verwendet. Beispielsweise sagt man "Der Bus, der zu spät kommt, ist auch noch überfüllt.", wenn man mit dem Nebensatz ausdrücken will, dass die Ankunft des Busses sich verzögert.

Und genau das ist das Problem mit den anderen Sätzen: Mit "Dieses Bild ist ein spätes Werk von XY" meint man *nicht*, dass das Bild irgendwo zu spät ankommt, sondern vielmehr, dass das Bild gegen Ende der Schaffenszeit von XY gemalt wurde.

Answer (score 0):

Da ist - meiner Auffassung nach - schon in der Prämisse der Wurm drin.

»Der späte Gast« ist für mich nämlich genauso undeutsch wie »der frühe Vogel« der seit wenigen Jahren durch die deutsche Sprache geistert. Da wird englische Grammatik in einem deutschen Kontext angewandt. Ein Gast kann nicht spät sein. Er kann spät kommen oder spät dran sein.

Das Spät-sein ist im Deutschen keine Eigenschaft einer Person, sondern eine Eigenschaft des gerade gezeigten Verhaltens der Person.

Möglicherweise unterliegt die deutsche Sprache in diesem Punkt auch gerade einem Wandel, und es wird bald als korrekt gelten, z.B. die Arbeitskollegen nicht nur als »der faule Bernhard«, »die hektische Erika«, »die allwissende Anna«, usw. zu bezeichnen, sondern vielleicht auch als »der frühe Walter« und »die späte Barbara«. Ich glaube aber, dass das noch nicht der Fall ist.

Comment: Mal ganz davon abgesehen, dass "the late guest" oder "the late Barbara" auf Englisch etwas vollkommen anderes heißt, als dass die Person (zu) spät ankommt.

Comment: -1 Auch wenn Du das vielleicht so wahrnimmst - die Phrase "ein später Gast" ist mindestens [bis ins 18. Jahrhundert zurück im deutschen Schriftgut zu finden](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22ein+sp%C3%A4ter+gast%22&hl=de&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A1900&tbm=bks).

Comment: @Matthias: Soweit ich das sehe, bedeutet "später Gast" aber auch in den über den Suchlink auffindbaren Beispielen (zumindest in der ersten Handvoll) wiederum etwas leicht anderes: Während ein Gast, der "spät dran" ist, relativ zur geplanten Ankunftszeit "spät" ist (was durchaus auch morgens um 8 sein kann, wenn die Ankunft eigentlich für 7:30 geplant oder angekündigt war), handelt es sich bei den "späten Gästen" in den Suchergebnissen, soweit ich das sehe, praktisch ausschließlich um Gäste, die gemessen an der absoluten Tageszeit "spät" ankommen, also zum Beispiel kurz vor Mitternacht.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Das ist mir schon klar. Um die Wendung "spät *dran* sein" geht es aber in *dieser* Frage überhaupt nicht. Sollte irgendjemand glauben, dass "spät sein" oder "ein später XY" neuerdings im Sinne von "being late" benutzt werden, möge er bitte eine eigene Frage aufmachen. Ich wollte wissen, warum ich jemanden, der zu später Stunde an die Tür klopft, nicht bezeichnen kann als "ein Gast, der spät ist".

Comment: @Matthias: 'Um die Wendung "spät dran sein" geht es aber in dieser Frage überhaupt nicht.' - ach so, entschuldigung, das war mir leider nicht klar, zumal auch [chirlu](http://german.stackexchange.com/users/2813/chirlu) gleich in seinem ersten Kommentar zur Frage auf "spät dran sein" verweist.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ah, stimmt. In dem Beispiel von chirlu wird durch das "dran" der Satz grammatikalisch richtig *und* behält die Bedeutung der attributiven Verwendung. Bei "spät" ändert sich hingegen die Bedeutung.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, late guests sind meist lebendig. Bei Eigennamen sollte man aber in der Tat vorsichtig sein.

Comment: Frühe Vögel gibt es auch schon lange, auch in einer Shakespeareübersetzung eines „bird of dawning“.

Comment: Auch Einsichten können nicht spät sein, sondern nur kommen, und werden doch späte genannt.

Comment: Auch "Mädchen" können durchaus spät sein. ;) "Das späte Mädchen" ist immerhin ein stehender Begriff. Dann gibt es noch den "späten Picasso"